# Can chrome extension modify a file in our hard drive?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, temporary-directory

I am making a chrome extension which needs to add/delete/modify file in any location in our hard drive. The location can be temporary folder. How is it possible to make it. Please give comments and helpful links which can lead to me have this work done.

Comment: Show us what code you have so far. Have you tried something like a web search for [chrome storage]? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1):

You can not, but adding a **local server** (nodejs/deno/cs-script/go/python/lua/..) to have a fixed logic (security) to do file stuff and **providing a http server** to answer back in an ajax/jsonp request would work.

The extension will not be able to install the software part.

**edit:** if you want to get started using nodejs, [this could help](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)

**edit2:** With `File and Directory Entries API` ([this could help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)) you can get hold of a FILE OR complete FOLDER ([`getDirectory()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryEntry/getDirectory), [`showDirectoryPicker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker)).

Comment: Chrome now supports the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), so it can modify local files without a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, this is impossible.

Google or any other company wouldn't have many friend if their extension(s') installation caused compromise including complete control over any files(ie. control over machine) on your hard drive. The extension can save information to disk in a location that is available for storing local information as mentioned. You will not have any execute permission on the root or anywhere nor will you have any read or write permission outside of the storage location.

However, extensions can still be malicious if they gather information from a user of a web page (I am sure that Google can filter some suspicious extensions).

If you really need to make changes on your hard drive you can store information on a server and poll for changes with a windows client application or perhaps you can find where the storage information is kept and access it from there from a windows app.

Comment: thanx jwize for your explanation. Can we make a folder in goole/chrome/app data ? As this place is already reserved for chrome.

Comment: I am not sure you can do this. As far as I can see if you go to %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage. I don't see any custom folders there. You can browse local storage files(.localstorage) with sqllite. http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/?source=dlp. I am sure  if you find a client library for sqllite you can manage the data from a windows app.

Comment: jwize is it something you saying? 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-dev-08

Comment: If you are installing dodgy extensions you're subject to a ton of risks that don't require local filesystem access.  I can't really agree with your logic that such a thing shouldn't be done for a security purposes.